# Update FireStore Document Id Using Flutter

Tags: flutter

> I want to update firestore document Id [Check This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkS2o.png)

Answer (score 0):

First, you cannot update the `id` of a document in Firestore. You will have to copy your document with the new id and delete the old one.

But why do you want to do this, especially within the `Users` collection? You will lose the link between the Firebase Auth Users and the Users details in your Firestore database.

Answer (score 0):

You can't update the document id directly. For that you first need to make a new document with your updated Id and then delete the previous one.

First of all you need to get the document and store the snapshot value in the variable document.

```
DocumentSnapshot snapshot= await Firestore.instance.collection('Users').document('yourId').get();
var document=snapshot.data;
```

After that you can

```
Firestore.instance.collection('Users').document('newId').setData(document);
Firestore.instance.collection('Users').document(document.id).delete();
```